Simulation using GPU
Is there a way to bake fluid simulations using my GPU instead of my CPU?
It takes a lot of time to bake fluid simulation using CPU. I am using Blender 4.1. I have a RTX 4060 and Ryzen 5 7600 CPU.

No, that's not how it's implemented in Blender. If it was, there would be an option to switch between CPU and GPU like there is for rendering or compositing.

Like I guessed. Thanks for answering though
